# Как вставить ссылку в css класс, с помощью JS

Tags: javascript, css, tilda

**Доброго времени суток!**

У меня есть css класс с параметром: **.js-store-filter-custom-select[data-filter-value="Верхняя одежда"]**

Как вставить в него ссылку ? Чтобы нажав по элементу с данным классом и параметром был переход на "**#mylink**"

(!) - страница на конструкторе, доступа к файлу стилей и любом бэку у меня нет.
Спасибо)

Comment: `#mylink` -- это же якорь? По идее Вам нужно добавить слушатель на клик по элементу `.js-store-filter-custom-select[data-filter-value="Верхняя одежда"]`, а потом уже делать перенаправление или скролить к якорю по клику.

Comment: Как это сделать в JS?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хорошо, предположим что это просто скролл к якорю. Находим кнопку по которой будем кликать и находим сам якорь. Вешаем лиснер на клик ивент на кнопку и добавляем плавный скролл к якорю с использованием [Window.scroll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll)

```js
const button = document.querySelector('.js-store-filter-custom-select[data-filter-value="Верхняя одежда"]');
const anchor = document.getElementById('mylink');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  window.scroll({
    top: anchor.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
});
```

```css
.scroll-section {
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<section class="scroll-section">
  <button class="js-store-filter-custom-select" data-filter-value="Верхняя одежда">Button</button>
  
  <h2 id="mylink">Anchor scroll to</h2>
</section>
```